# Query which gives products with only specific stages status

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a tables structure like this:

**PRODUCTS**

- Id_products
- Accepted

**PRODUCTS_STAGES**

- Id_products_stages
- Name

**PRODUCTS_STAGES**

- Id_products_stages
- Name

**PRODUCTS_STATUSES**

- Id_products_statuses
- Name
- Color

**PRODUCTS_STAGES_SET**

- Id_products_stages_set
- Id_products (fk)
- Id_products_stages (fk)

**PRODUCTS_STATUSES_SET**

- Id_products_statuses_set
- Id_products_statuses (fk)
- Id_products_stages_set (fk)

In PRODUCTS_STATUSES there are 4 statuses (Id-name):

- 1 - Notstarted
- 2 - Started
- 3 - Notfinished
- 4 - Finished

PRODUCTS_STAGES has 6 stages.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT p.Id_products FROM PRODUCTS AS p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT pss.Id_products FROM PRODUCTS_STAGES_SET AS pss
                    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_STATUSES_SET AS pss2 ON pss.Id_products_stages_set = pss2.Id_products_stages_set 
                    WHERE pss2.Id_products_statuses IN (1,2,3)
                    GROUP BY pss.Id_products) ps
ON p.Id_products = ps.Id_products
```

This query gives me products, which has **at least one** stage which is **NOT** finished

Now I want to have a query which gives me products which has a specific stage status only. For example I want to have products which has **stage2=Started**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.Id_products FROM PRODUCTS AS p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT pss.Id_products FROM PRODUCTS_STAGES_SET AS pss
                    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_STATUSES_SET AS pss2 ON pss.Id_products_stages_set = pss2.Id_products_stages_set 
                    WHERE pss2.Id_products_statuses = 2
                    GROUP BY pss.Id_products) ps
ON p.Id_products = ps.Id_products
```